WARNING: D8: An error occurred when parsing kotlin metadata
I recently update the gradle version of my project. And along with that I had to update the kotlin version. However when I run assembleRelease, I keep getting multiple warnings saying,
WARNING: D8: An error occurred when parsing kotlin metadata. This normally happens when using a newer version of kotlin than the kotlin version released when this version of R8 was created. To find compatible kotlin versions, please see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/kotlin-d8-r8-versions
WARNING: D8: Unexpected error during rewriting of Kotlin metadata for class 'com.google.firebase.analytics.ktx.ktxtesting.TestingKt':
com.android.tools.r8.internal.A10: Should never be called

This is my project level build.gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.android.gms:oss-licenses-plugin:0.10.6'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.4' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.4' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '3.0.2' apply false
}

and my gradle-wrapper.properties file looks like this
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

I also referred to https://developer.android.com/build/kotlin-support and it seems the versions shouldn't be incompatible based on the information provided.
I am getting the above warnings only for com.google.firebase.analytics .
Any assistance to solve this will be greatly appreciated.

I am working on D8. This is only a warning, and if Kotlin reflect is not used it should be benign. This could bean issue in the library used and not D8. That said, AGP 8.1.4, is quite old, 8.6.0 was recently released. Do you get the same error with that version? If you cannot upgrade AGP it might be possible to just update D8/R8 to the latest stable, 8.6.28. See https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/ae439ef04f55a994b195a3a89315ed64d7d2245e/README.md#replacing-r8-in-agp for details. Otherwise, please file an issue with https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=317603.

@sgjesse Thank you for your prompt response. I updated the AGP to the latest version and warnings disappeared. Thank you :)

Upgrading AGP to the latest version (which at the time of writing is 8.6.0) fixed this issue (see the question comments above).
